# How to include to add more than just message to an error object in express?

Tags: javascript, express

I want to add 2 pieces of information to the error in express to get passed to my error handler which will send both of those pieces of info in JSON to the client. Right now I can do this:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      var err = new Error('test error 1');
       err.status = 404;
    next(err);
     });
```

But I don't just want the message I also want to be able to attach the position so that the client knows where to display the message. Something like this:

```
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
      var err = new Error({err: {pos: 'field3', msg: 'test error 1'}});
       err.status = 404;
    next(err);
     });
```

and then send that info to the client like this:

```
 app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json(err.message);
 });
```

But this doesn't work because when I create the error object it will only take one string in the message. How can I pass on 2 pieces of information in my error handling middleware (ideally an object with more than 2 parts if I wanted to)?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like ,

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(404).json({
     message: 'Not Found',
     message2: 'error'
  });
}
```

Comment: This is what I am doing now but from a lot of the code I am seeing online. The pattern most people use is to use the error object and then next(err) and then at the end of the process you have an error handler that actually sends the error. I think this is for stack tracing and logging purposes. I am newer at express and wanted to try to go with the best way. Do you see any disadvantage to me sticking with your way (current way I handle errors) comapred to the way I am seeing most people do that I just described?

Comment: i am not sure about your method but this is what i am using in my development of projects, You can stick to any of this.
and if you are handling errors front side also i suggest you to go through `express-validators` and `Connect-flash` , `express-session`